# Modifying this SQLite helper class to insert records on database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an application which uses a database and I'm using an helper class someone suggested me here in stackoverflow.

The helper class is this one (a jar file is also needed) : https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

I'll transcribe it here:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
}

public Cursor getItems() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "ItemName", "ItemCategory"}; 
    String sqlTables = "ShopItems";
    String selection = "ItemCategory='1'";    
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, selection, null,
            null, null, null);  

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

}
```

}

This works like a charm. However, i need to add a method to insert new records into a table and i'm not figuring out how to do that. Can someone help me, or point me to a link/tutorial? Thanks

EDIT: i don't know if it's relevant, but i'm using a prepopulated database on the assets folder.

Comment: Here is a reference may give some pointers http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/how-to-insert-data-in-to-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

try using `ContentValues` to insert data in DB

```
openDB();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("column1", valuel);
cv.put("column2", value2);//and so on...
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
closeDB();
```

hope it helps...